# column_property works pretty bad in combination with datetime.now()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use `column_property` of SqlAlchemy in order to have my attributes loaded at query time (to have 1 query and not n+1).

The code looks like:

```
class Whatever(db.Model):
  from datetime import datetime as dt
  prio_event = column_property(func.synthetise_events_with_date(id, dt.now()), deferred=True)
```

The code is mostly working but during tests, I run into some issues: somehow SQLAlchemy caches the result of dt.now().

Given the following query:

```
q = Whatever.query.filter(whatever).options(undefer(Job.prio_event))
```

If you call this at `time t` and at `time t + 20 sec`, the query will have the same second params (the date will be `t` in both cases).

The question is, **is there a more elegant solution than doing a basic join instead of column property** (which will work because the params will be calculated at runtime)? Hybrid property doesn't seem to be the way because you cannot load it at query time.

Comment: A wild guess is that the cokumn_property is "materialised" on first usage and will therefore "frezze" the Python values. Have you tried using `func.now()` instead of `dt.now()`? Or are you required to use `dt.now()`?

Comment: `func.now()` would work but not with unit test: I fake the datetime for testing purposes

Comment: Within the same transaction, all calls to `NOW()` (as well as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` & co) will always return the same time. Maybe that will help you with the unit-tests. You can run a simple `SELECT NOW()` to get the current transaction's timestamp, then use that for comparisons. That way, no faking/patching is even needed.